# Uploading a document from Windows Store App to a SharePoint 2013 document library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I need to upload a document to a SharePoint 2013 document library (can be via Rest Api/other) using C# & also retrieve the unique id/location of the document currently uploaded. Please suggest to me a recommended way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of uploading a file and using the server response to get the ID of the document which can be used to get the location though the response may also contain the URL of the document if you poke through the JSON.

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
// Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
picker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
// Open the file picker.
StorageFile path = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (path != null)
{
     string url = "https://YourSite.com/Subsite/";
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
     client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");
     IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await path.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
     var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
     await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
     Byte[] content = new byte[fileStream.Size];
     reader.ReadBytes(content);
     ByteArrayContent file = new ByteArrayContent(content);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("_api/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?@TargetLibrary='Project Photos'&@TargetFileName='TestUpload.jpg'", file);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     { 
        //Get file ID from SharePoint
        var info = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JsonObject d = JsonValue.Parse(info.Result).GetObject();
        string id = d["d"].GetObject()["ListItemAllFields"].GetObject().GetNamedValue("ID").Stringify();
     }
 }
```

'digest' is a string you have to retrieve from SharePoint to authenticate any further REST calls.  You can find an example of how to do that and any other common task for a Store App for SharePoint  here:

https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-services-using-c-and-the-httpclient-for-windows-store-apps/

Comment: You should probably retitle the question to reference that this is for Windows Store Apps.  For non Store code there is much easier ways of accomplishing this task.

Comment: How will the application manage the SharePoint access credentials? Do i need to add some .dll that will ask for credentials or manually specify credentials or how is it exactly?

Comment: It will use the currently logged on user by default but you can also specify the credentials when you create the HttpClient.  In the examples I provided it will use the currently logged on user as is.

Comment: Appreciate your great help. I would like to use a (.net) web service to upload a document to a library & return the unique id of the document.

Comment: Are you going to run this on the SharePoint server instead of as a Windows Store app then?  You would only use the examples for the store as I noted above.  From anywhere else you can use CSOM to achieve this goal in half the code.

Comment: I would like to use CSOM to achieve file upload & retrieve the uique id of the document. The service will not be deployed on sharepoint server.

Comment: CSOM is very well documented and easy to use.  You should be able to find plenty of examples.

Comment: The digest is just like a cookie more or less.  It's a string for tracking your session once you have authenticated.  If you share your Skype ID I would be happy to contact you.  I am unaware of how to do this privately and don't really feel like posting it out to everyone.